# Object/factory with type AuthBloc is not registered inside GetIt. (using injectable)

Tags: flutter, dependency-injection, initialization

while I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65145482/flutter-injectable-factory-not-registered-error) answer for the same issue, it doesn't resolve mine. This is error is typically thrown if one forgets await the initialization, but I believe to have (now) implemented this correctly according the various answers that I studied.

Starting my app fails with the above error always with the initial try. Upon hot restart, it then typically works, occasionally it throws this error again.

This is how the code looks like:

`lib/injection.dart`

```dart
final GetIt getIt = GetIt.instance;
@injectableInit
@preResolve
Future<void> configureInjection(String env) async {
  $initGetIt(getIt, environment: env);
}
```

`main()`

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await configureInjection(Environment.prod);
  runApp(App());
}
```

And it fails on the router of the SplashPage here:

```dart
class AppRouter extends _i1.RootStackRouter {
  AppRouter([_i2.GlobalKey<_i2.NavigatorState>? navigatorKey])
      : super(navigatorKey);

  @override
  final Map<String, _i1.PageFactory> pagesMap = {
    SplashRoute.name: (routeData) => _i1.AdaptivePage<dynamic>(
        routeData: routeData,
// >>>>>>> SplashPage behind _i3. of following line is highlighted with error
        builder: (_) {return _i3.SplashPage();}),
    SignInRoute.name: (routeData) => _i1.AdaptivePage<dynamic>(
        routeData: routeData,
        builder: (_) {return _i4.SignInPage();}),
    HomeRoute.name: (routeData) => _i1.AdaptivePage<dynamic>(
        routeData: routeData,
        builder: (_) {return _i5.HomePage();}),
  };

  @override
  List<_i1.RouteConfig> get routes => [
        _i1.RouteConfig(SplashRoute.name, path: '/'),
        _i1.RouteConfig(SignInRoute.name, path: '/sign-in-page'),
        _i1.RouteConfig(HomeRoute.name, path: '/home-page'),
      ];
}
```

And this is the error

```dart
Object/factory with  type AuthBloc is not registered inside GetIt. 
(Did you accidentally do GetIt sl=GetIt.instance(); instead of GetIt sl=GetIt.instance;
Did you forget to register it?)
'package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart':
Failed assertion: line 372 pos 7: 'instanceFactory != null'

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  SplashPage file:///Users/admin/IdeaProjects/newProject/lib/presentation/routes/router.gr.dart:24:22
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      _GetItImplementation._findFactoryByNameAndType (package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart:372:7)
#3      _GetItImplementation.get (package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart:393:29)
#4      _GetItImplementation.call (package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart:430:12)
#5      App.build.<anonymous closure> (package:newProject/app.dart:40:33)
#6      _CreateInheritedProviderState.value (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:687:36)
...
```

Comment: It appears as awaiting `configureInjection` does not await the full extent of initialization. If I await a Future Duration in between to setting up the BlocProvider of AuthBloc, the issue vanishes.